# C# timer - statistics

Tags: c#, .net

I have question consider making statistics process. For the first I want to save to the .txt file time when one of the label have specific value with specific date.

For example when label1 have value=“Good” we start counting time and then if label1 change value counting time is stop.

How can I do that ? I mean I have to use timer or stopwatch ?

Answer (score 1):

I think here both `Timer` and `Stopwatch` would be useless.

When your `Label` text became "Good" - you should store current time with `DateTime.Now` (for example, to variable `dt1`). Then, when sometime text changed again - you again capture `DateTime.Now` (for example, to another variable `dt2`). Both `DateTime`s you can compare and calculate the difference (inverval) by subtracting them:

```
TimeSpan interval = dt2 - dt1;
// or
DateTime interval = new DateTime((dt2 - dt1).Ticks);
```

`inverval` will store amount of time that passed between changes.

If you provide info about type of your application (WPF, WinForms) - probably I would help you with code example.

Reproduced example on Windows Forms application. **Just for example**:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{    
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Random rnd = new Random();

        // Setting label text with random string
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string labelText = string.Empty;

                if (rnd.Next(1, 20) > 10)
                    labelText = "Good";
                else
                {
                    int randomStringLength = rnd.Next(1, 10);
                    labelText = GenerateRandomString(randomStringLength);
                }

                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { label1.Text = labelText; });
                await Task.Delay(rnd.Next(1000, 5000));
            }
        });
    }

    private DateTime dt1 = DateTime.MinValue;
    private DateTime dt2 = DateTime.MinValue;

    private void OnLabelTextChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (label1.Text == "Good")
            dt1 = DateTime.Now;
        else
        {
            if (dt1 != DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                dt2 = DateTime.Now;
                TimeSpan interval = dt2 - dt1;
                string passedTime = "Time passed since label1.Text was equal \"Good\": " + interval.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
                string lastChangeTime = "Last label1.Text change was at: " + dt2.ToUniversalTime().ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss") + " (UTC)";

                MessageBox.Show(passedTime + Environment.NewLine + lastChangeTime);
                // or File.AppendAllText("MyLog.txt", passedTime + Environment.NewLine + lastChangeTime)
            }
        }
    }

    public static string GenerateRandomString(int length) =>
        new string(Enumerable.Repeat("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefjhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", length)
             .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
             .ToArray());
}
```

Sample output:

[image]

Feel free to edit, use and corrent me.

Comment: Subtracting _DateTimes_ gives _TimeSpans_

Comment: Sorry, true. Edited.

Comment: TimeSpans are much easier to format (`.TotalSeconds`) etc than DateTimes. leave it a Timespan.. ;-)

Comment: It might be better (and faster) to record the times of the change events. This allows to calculate intervals between different events and reduces the number of calculations in the program.

Comment: In this case, a label is used, so whenever you write `good` in that label, pinpoint the current time. Same with something other that `good`... It's not user input...